# How to make a clicable circle inside of map with android studio

Tags: android

I draw a circle inside my map, and I just want to make a event. The way I'm doing, its not working.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-8.161908, -34.917295);
            mMap = googleMap;
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));

            if(marker == null){
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
            }else {
                marker.setPosition(latLng);
            }


            CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
            circleOptions.center(new LatLng(-8.162686, -34.922391));
            circleOptions.radius(20);
            circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
            circleOptions.fillColor(0x30ff0000);
            circleOptions.strokeWidth(2);
            circleOptions.isClickable();
            mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

            mMap.setOnCircleClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCircleClick(Circle circle) {
                    Toast.makeText(DrawerActivity.this, "DADADADAD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

In the [Reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) documentation it says that :

> Gets the clickability of the circle. If the circle is clickable, your app will receive notifications to the GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener when the user clicks the circle. The event listener is registered through setOnCircleClickListener(GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener).

Comment: Try using some elevation on the circle `ViewCompat.setElevation(circleOptions , 8)`

Comment: meaning what  ??

Answer (score 1):

instead of `circleOptions.isClickable ();`
put `circleOptions.clickable (true);`